# Any common reference for linear, TIME-VARYING systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, signal-processing, nonlinear-dynamics

This isn't exactly a math question (apologies!), but it could prevent many potential misunderstandings I might otherwise encounter in the near future (and also prevent many dumb questions I will post here otherwise). What is a common reference for linear, time-varying systems?

I saw two references: **Linear System Theory** by *Wilson Rugh*, and **Control of Linear Parameter Varying Systems with Applications** by *Mohammadpour and Scherer*.

**Background**

Recurrent neural networks (RNNs) and structured state-space models (SSMs) have been suffering from the vanishing/exploding gradient problem. Recent progress in sequence modeling suggests that these problems stem from time-invariance. I am wondering where I should start to catch up on the general knowledge of time-variant systems.

Comment: "Time" and "system" mean different things in different contexts, and the continuous-time dynamical systems and differential equations you'll encounter in control theory are not directly applicable to the theory of recurrent neural networks or the vanishing gradient problem. I'd suggest starting your research closer to the problem you want to work on.